# Bootstrap File Input - set value in function

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, file, input, plugins

I use this JS plugin:
http://plugins.krajee.com/file-input

I try set value for file-input in other function.
My code:

```
function edit(obj){

$("#file").fileinput({
    'allowedFileExtensions' : ['jpg', 'png','gif'],
    showUpload: false,

   <?php
    $filename = "../images/about/bg.jpg";
    $bytes = filesize($filename);

    echo "initialPreview: [";
    // IMAGE DATA
    echo "'".$filename."'],";
    echo "initialPreviewAsData: true,";
    echo "initialPreviewFileType: 'image',";
    echo "initialPreviewConfig: [";

    echo "{showDelete: false, size: ".$bytes.", width: '100px'}, ]";
    ?>

    });
}
```

It does't work.
When I take code

```
...$("#file").fileinput({...
```

outside is ok.
I want to have this action after click edit button.

Comment: you cannot set the value of a file input programmatically. this would be a security issue if it was possible.